# Strange Forms Authentication Expiration behaviour leading up to DST End

Tags: c#, asp.net, cookies, forms-authentication, dst

I have an ASP.NET web application that uses Forms Authentication. We witnessed some strange behaviour on our live website on 25th October between 1am-2am (in the UK, DST ended at 2am 25/10/2015 and the clocks went back an hour), whereby all users are signed out as the authentication ticket looks to be expired by the following code:

```
protected void Application_BeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    HttpCookie cookie = Request.Cookies["MyCookie"];

    FormsAuthenticationTicket ticket;
    try
    {
        ticket = FormsAuthentication.Decrypt(cookie.Value);
    }
    catch
    {
        this.RedirectDueToError(ErrorView);
        return;
    }

    if (ticket == null) { return; }

    if (ticket.Expiration < DateTime.Now)
    {
        this.RedirectDueToError(TimeoutView);
    }
}
```

The Web.config contains:

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
    <forms name="MyCookie" timeout="40" requireSSL="false"/>
</authentication>
```

I've reproduced the problem on a test server and can see the issues occurs between 1am and 2am **prior** to DST ending. When the time reaches 2am and is automatically changed back an hour to 1am the problem is resolved.

During my test I added some extra logging to determine the values of the `ticket.Expiration` and `DateTime.Now` at the point of failure (which was also just after the authentication ticket was originally created). The results were:

Prior to DST ending:
Server Time: 00:53:39
`DateTime.Now` = 00:53:39
`ticket.Expiration` = 01:33:37 (correct)

Prior to DST ending:
Server Time: 01:25:08
`DateTime.Now` = 01:25:08
`ticket.Expiration` = 01:05:08 (wrong)

Post DST ending:
Server Time: 01:35:06
`DateTime.Now` = 01:35:06
`ticket.Expiration` = 02:15:06 (correct)

So it seems in the hour prior to DST ending, the time returned from the `FormsAuthenticationTicket` `Expiration` property is an hour behind. I understand the Expiration time is stored as UTC internally, but the `Expiration` property is a local time and suspect there's a problem in the conversion.

Any ideas why this would be? Code issue? Server Issue?

Comment: See the note [here](http://www.asp.net/web-forms/overview/older-versions-security/introduction/forms-authentication-configuration-and-advanced-topics-vb). It seems like this behaviour is by design?

Comment: I also read that link. It mentions clocks going forward but doesn't mention DST ending. In my scenario, everybody who logged in from 1am-2am, were signed out straight away as the expiry was already in the past. Surely, that can't be by design?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The crux of the problem is here:

```
if (ticket.Expiration < DateTime.Now)
```

Change this to either:

```
if (ticket.Expiration.ToUniversalTime() < DateTime.UtcNow)
```

Or better, to this, which does the same thing internally:

```
if (ticket.Expired)
```

The problem is actually detailed verbosely [in the comments found in the MSDN reference sources](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Web/Security/FormsAuthenticationTicket.cs,83).

Basically it comes down to the design of the `DateTime` structure.  Comparison of two `DateTime` objects only considers its `Ticks` value, not its `Kind`, so it does not take DST or time zone into account.

Also, I normally recommend against using `ToUniversalTime`, but in this particular case, it is ok.